# Android draw rounded rectangle in Android UI

Tags: android, user-interface, shapes

I want draw shape like on image, how I can do this?[image]

Answer (score 5):

make xml drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@color/red" />

    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

And set this drawable as imageview background

Comment: Note: the height of the ImageView must be `2 * radius` (in this case, 20dp), to get the desired "perfect round" effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can either follow the approach Bhargav suggested above with .xml files by using shape or layers (You can find many guides to do so) or you can use Picasso Library with many features like this one as well. Picasso makes many things easy as this, I suggest you to use Picasso.